# newbie javascript scope problem

Tags: google-maps, javascript

I know a bit about what scope is, i am new to javascript and have hit a full stop in my code. Here is the code that i use.

```
function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.775057,-122.419624),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
          mapOptions);
      }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function clicked(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'response.php',
    data: {id: id},
    success: function (lats) {
      var obj = $.parseJSON(lats);
      var line = [];
      for (var i = obj.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        line.push(new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].latitude, obj[i].longitude));
      };
      var polyPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: line,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
      polyPath.setMap(map);
      console.log(polyPath);
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Needless to say its google maps.
Problem is that due to scope, javascript cant access the map variable that is required to draw the polylines. Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

because `map` is declared inside the function `initialize`, `clicked` can't access it you need to declare it outside initialize like

```
var map = null;
function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.775057,-122.419624),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
          mapOptions);
    }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function clicked(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'response.php',
    data: {id: id},
    success: function (lats) {
      var obj = $.parseJSON(lats);
      var line = [];
      for (var i = obj.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        line.push(new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].latitude, obj[i].longitude));
      };
      var polyPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: line,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
      polyPath.setMap(map);
      console.log(polyPath);
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

now `clicked` can access it because it's outside the `initialize` scope

Answer (score 1):

You can move `map` to the global scope.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    ...
    map = ....;
}
```

If you're concerned with polluting the global scope, you can put both inside a single function to preserve the namespace:

```
(function() {
     var map;
     function initialize() {
         ...
         map = ....;
     }
     ...(everything else) ...
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to getting the map variable from your `initialize` function, here is what you would need to do.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.775057,-122.419624),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function clicked(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'response.php',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function (lats) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(lats);
            var line = [];
            for (var i = obj.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                line.push(new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].latitude, obj[i].longitude));
            };
            var polyPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: line,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
            polyPath.setMap(map);
            console.log(polyPath);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

What I have done is declare `map` outside the initialize function. In this case, it will have global scope to all of your Javascript code that you can call later. The initialize function will be able to set it for you and the AJAX call will be able to read it.

An alternative to declaring `map` outside of the initialise function would be using `window.map` which assigns it as the map property on the window object. As the window object can be accessed anywhere as it is global, you just need to call `window.map` to read and write to it anywhere.

Comment: try in the console `var iDontKnowAGoodVarName = "Hello window!";console.log(window.iDontKnowAGoodVarName);`, a var will be automatically be attached to the window if its not executed in any scope :)

Comment: Yep. When in a function though, to get it on the window object you manually need to have `window.YOUR_VAR` otherwise it is stuck in local scope.

Comment: false, check it `window.stillDontKnowAGoodOne = "Inception v2.1b";(function(){ console.log(stillDontKnowAGoodOne); })()`,

Comment: or did you mean assign it to the `window` object?

Comment: I mean more like this: `(function(){window.myVar="abc";})(); //myVar=="abc" : true`

Comment: Then you're right, Yes :) Today I learned new stuff about the crazy window scope tho. what a mess.

Answer (score 0):

A quick but not recommended solution would be to remove the `var` in front of map making it a global variable.

Comment: If you use global variables for everything, other code might get in conflict when using the same name

Comment: you only need to be that strict when writing a plugin or something, there is nothing wrong with using _global_ variables in your project, as long as you have a list with all the global's at the top :) so you don't get conflicts ;)

Comment: I was such a dumbass on May 6 2013. Globals are bad. Globals are a nono ew.